# Command Prompt Doesn't Open

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe

Hi I have just stumbled upon a weird problem and spent an hour trying to find the same problem on the internet but it's nowhere to be found.I am using windows 10.Here is the problem.

When I start my machine the command prompt opens for a split second and closes after that my computer opens up(The folder).When I try to open the command prompt myself it does the same thing.I have a plugin that I am using on atom which embeds the command prompt in it.I tried to use the command prompt from there and again I can't use it but this time I can see the error its presenting.Here is the error which is the only clue I can provide about this problem.

```
The screen cannot be set to the number of lines and columns specified.
```

Any ideas on how to fix this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue and it was related to mining malware installed on my machine. To resolve:

1. Delete the SoundMixer file and folder in your app data:  %appdata%\Microsoft\Microsoft\SoundMixer\SoundMixer.exe
2. Go to windows registry and go to HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command
   Processor and remove key AutoRun.

source: https://forums.windowscentral.com/windows-10/466299-unable-launch-command-prompt.html

Comment: This fixed it for me

Comment: Exact answer I needed. Worked.

Comment: I didn't have anything do do with SoundMixer, but removing the place stated AuroRun key from there fixed the problem on my computer.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you have set the width and/height to an incorrect number.

To fix this, open the startmenu and search for Command Prompt. But don't open it. Instead, right-click it and select properties.

Head over to the layout tab and reset its settings to the default: width: 80, height: 25 and press ok.

The problem should now be solved.

Comment: Unfortunately when i check the layout tab they are already at their default value.

Comment: And when you run that command prompt, it still vanishes with the same error?

Comment: Yes It does.I tried to reset the HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Console file by deleting it from regedit but it didn't have any effect.